# SQL Optimization - Query take 15 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have 400 rows every tables. So, I will try to relationship every tables using `LEFT JOIN` based on ID, but my query takes 15 seconds, and this is my query:

```
SELECT
  sender.id AS id,
  sender.letter AS letter,
  sender.date AS date,
  mediaseller.contract_number AS contract,
  sender.company AS company,
  brand.value AS brand,
  sender.message_category AS message_category,
  sender.message_format AS message_format,
  sender.senderid AS senderid,
  cpname.value AS cpname,
  sid.value AS sid,
  status.status AS status,
  sender.remarks AS remarks,
  user.name AS name,
  sender.id AS download,
  mediaseller.value AS mediaseller,
  lob.value AS lob,
  lob.subvalue AS sublob,
  sms_type.value AS type_sms,
  status.approval_date,
  status.batch_date, 
  status.done_date,
  status.decline_date
FROM status
  LEFT JOIN sender ON status.trxid = sender.trxid
  LEFT JOIN user ON status.userid = user.id
  LEFT JOIN mediaseller ON sender.mediaseller = mediaseller.id
  LEFT JOIN lob ON sender.industry_category = lob.id
  LEFT JOIN sms_type ON sender.type_sms = sms_type.id
  LEFT JOIN cpname ON sender.cpname = cpname.id
  LEFT JOIN sid ON sender.trxid = sid.trxid
  LEFT JOIN brand ON sender.brand = brand.id
WHERE status.hidden = 0
ORDER BY status.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

I hopeful is query takes one seconds :D
Please give me advice, Thankyou!

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: why you think like that can you plz explain to us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not filtering by anything other than the status.  So try this:

```
FROM (SELECT s.*
      FROM status s
      WHERE s.hidden = 0
      ORDER BY status.id DESC
      LIMIT 10
     ) status
  LEFT JOIN sender ON status.trxid = sender.trxid
  LEFT JOIN user ON status.userid = user.id
  LEFT JOIN mediaseller ON sender.mediaseller = mediaseller.id
  LEFT JOIN lob ON sender.industry_category = lob.id
  LEFT JOIN sms_type ON sender.type_sms = sms_type.id
  LEFT JOIN cpname ON sender.cpname = cpname.id
  LEFT JOIN sid ON sender.trxid = sid.trxid
  LEFT JOIN brand ON sender.brand = brand.id
WHERE status.hidden = 0
ORDER BY status.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

You still need the outer `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, but they should be on much less data resulting in a performance improvement.

Note:  I assume that you have declared all the `id`s as primary keys, so they have indexes.

Comment: Only if any of the `LEFT JOINs` delivers more than 1 row, then the outer `LIMIT` is necessary.  The outer `WHERE` should be unnecessary.